# How to draw an animated point to point line in grapher

Tags: grapher

I am using grapher and want o create some animations for a PHY class. I have figured out how to animate a dot moving in a circle, and what I am trying to do is draw a line from the dot as i moves around to a fixed point. What I have is a t=0 as my parameter, and I am using the animate parameter function with a like matrix set up in x,y, where x=cos(t) and y = sin(t). I also managed o have a line go from the center to the dot and follow it around, but I want the line to stop at the dot and set it up so it runs from off-center. (The whole point is to illustrate the difference between distance from a starting point and displacement).

Anyhow this is what I have so far, if anyone has suggestions that would be most appreciated. (I want to draw a line from the edge of the circle on the x-axis to the blue dot, so you can see the length change as it moves) [image]